# Why does adding a number to a string show up as object undefined

Tags: javascript

```js
var person = "person" + toString(0);

console.log(person);
```

Why does the output of this make person[object undefined] instead of person0

Comment: Because you're using [toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) wrong. `toString(0)` is not the same as `var a = 0; var person = "person" + a.toString();` Please see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cr1zy7d6/) for an example

Answer (score 1):

So, to follow from my comment, you are using the [toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) method completely wrong.

You are doing the following;

```
var person = "person" + toString(0);

console.log(person);
```

Giving you the result of `person[object Undefined]`

However, if you have the following;

```
var num = 0;
var person = "person" + num.toString();
console.log(person);
```

This will result in `person0` from the console.log

Please see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cr1zy7d6/) for a working example

Answer (score 0):

the toString() does not take any arguments. Remove your arguments and you can use this as `'person' + String(0)`